# How to increase speed of searching in different phases (total, hot, warm) in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Search slowdown of up to 1 minute when an index goes into warm state
When an index is transferred from the Hot to the Warm, in this situation, after the implementation of a query and because the alias used is the same for total indexes,
The high response time in warm indexes increases the overall response time of the query

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected the search to take more time if index is not in the hot nodes, so if you are having a single alias which searches data in slower tier, it will impact the overall search response time.

If you are actively searching on the slower tier, first you should not move them to slower tier, and if you are not actively searching them then you should remove it from your alias and create a separate alias for slower tier, that way when you are not searching in slower tier, your response would be faster, and when you need to search on slower tier its expected to be slower, **but you should definitely don't mix all of them in single alias**.

Comment: now, elastic search data first on hot phases, if find it, next search on warm and then cold , ... . I want find data on hot return data and don't search on next phases.

Comment: @Imlucky as suggested, instead of a single alias pointing to all tier, you should have a different alias and always search on the alias/index which is on hot phase

Comment: How to create different alias? Can you give an example? Thank you! I am confused.